# Placing Element on top of the other

Tags: jquery

I have a table with 2 columns. When the user clicks on any cell of Column 2, it should overlay a div on 'that cell' which should top left aligned to the cell that was clicked, with absolute positioning.

How can we do it. This what I have done so far (not working code)

```
var $divOverlay = $('#divOverlay');
        var bottomWidth = $(this).css('width');
        var bottomHeight = $(this).css('height');
        var rowPos = $(this).position();
        bottomTop = rowPos.top;
        bottomLeft = rowPos.left;
        $divOverlay.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: bottomTop,
            right: '0px',
            width: '80%',
            height: '500px'
        });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v4dXn/14/

Comment: Why not just change the background color of the cell ?

Comment: Just add `left: bottomLeft` to the properties. http://jsfiddle.net/v4dXn/15/

Comment: The overlay appears from Column 1. My task is to make overlay appear in Column 2 cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be my approach. Note how the class initially has the position and left offsets that we need, also, that we just append it to the element as needed.

```
$('td').on('click', function(){
    var $this = $(this),
    $divOverlay = $('#divOverlay');

    $divOverlay.css({
        height:$this.height(),
        width:$this.outerWidth()
    }).appendTo($this).show();

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J6NU8/)

**Note -**

You only need the `outerWidth()` if you're using padding on the cells instead of a hard width value, in case you're using some type of responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var $divOverlay = $('#divOverlay');
        var bottomWidth = $('tr').css('width');   //Get the width of the tr
        var bottomHeight = $('tr').css('height'); //Get the height of the tr 
        var rowPos = $(this).position();
        bottomTop = rowPos.top;
        bottomLeft = rowPos.left;
        $divOverlay.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: bottomTop,            
            width: bottomWidth,  //assign here
            height: bottomHeight //assign here
        });
        ....
        ....
```

[**Update fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/v4dXn/16/)

Comment: The overlay appears from Column 1. My task is to make overlay appear in Column 2 cell

Answer (score 0):

I believe in this case you should use `.offset` instead of `.position`, since the elements don't share the same parent.
http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Also add: `left : bottomLeft`